# SQL conditional join with condition priorities like in CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

How to join conditionally on (1) full key OR (2) part of the key, if first condition is not met. Suppose id consists of 7 characters.

```
select 
a.id,
coalesce (t.somevalue, t2.somevalue)
from a

left join t
on a.id=t.id

left join t as t2
on left(a.id,6)=left(t2.id,6)
```

Is the above join possible in one shot? Something like this but maintaining priority of full key join over part key join?

```
left join t
on 
a.id=t.id OR left(a.id,6)=left(t2.id,6)
```

I wonder if there is something like

```
left join t
on 
case when condition 1
case when condition 2
```

Here is sample data and expected results.

```
+---------+
|  a.id   |
+---------+
| aaaaa0A |
| aaaaa0B |
| aaaaa1A |
| aaaaa2A |
| aaaaa3B |
+---------+

+---------+
| t.id    |
+---------+
| aaaaa0C |
| aaaaa1B |
| aaaaa1A |
| aaaaa2B |
| aaaaa3A |
+---------+

+---------+---------+--------------+
| a.id    | t.id    | condition no |
+---------+---------+--------------+
| aaaaa0A | aaaaa0C | 2            |
| aaaaa0B | aaaaa0C | 2            |
| aaaaa1A | aaaaa1A | 1            |
| aaaaa2A | aaaaa2B | 2            |
| aaaaa3B | aaaaa3A | 2            |
+---------+---------+--------------+
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Have you tried your example queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `outer apply`:

```
select a.id, t.somevalue
from a outer apply
     (select top (1) t.*
      from t
      where left(a.id, 6) = left(t.id, 6)
      order by (case when a.id = t.id then 1 else 2 end)  -- put full matches first
     ) t;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do a 2nd `LEFT` join of `t` under the condition that the 1st join does not match:

```
select 
  a.id,
  coalesce(t1.id, t2.id) id,
  case 
    when t1.id is not null then 1
    when t2.id is not null then 2
    else 0
  end [condition no] 
from a
left join t as t1 on a.id = t1.id
left join t as t2 on t1.id is null and left(a.id, 6) = left(t2.id, 6)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=97cfb642273f22ba8119852e4d6df438).
Results:

```
> id      | id      | condition no
> :------ | :------ | -----------:
> aaaaa0A | aaaaa0C |            2
> aaaaa0B | aaaaa0C |            2
> aaaaa1A | aaaaa1A |            1
> aaaaa2A | aaaaa2B |            2
> aaaaa3B | aaaaa3A |            2
```

Comment: As long as we use coalesce then in the second join the part which denies the first condition is redundant. It is more clear to stick to my original code.

Comment: It is not redundant in the case the condition `left(a.id, 6) = left(t2.id, 6)` joins on more than 1 rows because it happens that the first 6 chars are the same. You don't want all these rows returned in that case.

Comment: Your second join is not a protection against multiplication of rows in my case because I have aaaaa2A, aaaaa2B, aaaaa2A in the t table. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6342eaab1b8bad11d861ada45a90ee68 Sorry, I was not precise enough because I did not include such cases in sample data. Outer apply is exactly what I wanted. Thank you for your effort.